# Do the $n\times n$ matrices over a division ring $D$ form a free $D$-module?

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules

Let $D$ be a division ring. Then the set of $n\times n$ matrices over $D$ is free as a
              $D$-module.

I think this is wrong because they are linearly dependent, right?

But what does the given of $D$ as a division ring changes ?

Comment: Changes much. If I remember correctly, *every* module over a division ring is free.

Comment: because a unitary R module is a vector space ! right ,thank you

Comment: over a division ring

Comment: And Berci is exactly right: every module over a division ring is free. But you can say more for the particular question in the body here.

Answer (score 1):

It's easy to see that $M_n(R)$ is isomorphic to the direct sum of $n^2$ copies of $R$ as an $R$ module for any ring $R$.

It's clearly free and has a basis consisting of the "unit matrices" $E_{ij}$ that are $1$ on the $i,j$ entry and zero elsewhere.